# Fair coins or not

Tags: probability

I am reading [Introduction to Probability, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/188652923X), and at the end of chapter one the following problem appears:

> We are given three coins: one has 'heads' in both faces, the second has
> tails in both faces, and the third has a 'head' in one face and a tail in the other. We
> choose a coin at random, toss it, and the result is 'heads'. What is the probability that
> the opposite face is tails?

I solve it assuming the general case where the coin might not be fair so I assume that the probability of having a 'head' in the second coin is `p`.

And the other two coins would not be affected by the nature of the coin.

But the solution manual which was written by the same author assumes that the coins are fair.

So what's is the right thing to assume?

Comment: When talking about coins, dice, balls, cards, and so on, the standard assumption is that they are fair, unless something else is specifically written in the text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is 'right' or 'wrong' here as the exercise was poorly worded. I personally would interpret the third coin as 50:50 for the lack of information, but your interpretation is equally reasonable. For what it's worth, you solved a generalization of the exercise and therefore would receive full credit in case this was an exam (at least if it was one of mine).

Comment: So there is no convention of what to do when nothing mentions if the coins were fair?
or like the comment of @YJT ?

Comment: @KaisHasan There might be a convention in the book, you should check, in which case the convention applies. But otherwise I would find it unfair to the reader if there was some sort of meta convention going on because how would a beginner know? I tend to agree with YJT that (also colloquially) the standard assumption is that coins are fair, but as I said, your assumption is perfectly reasonable as well.

Answer (score 0):

The second coin, which has *head* on one side and *tail* on the other is assumed to be fair in the sense that both outcomes are equally likely. And we only need to consider the *HH* coin and *HT* coin for computing the indicated *Pr* because the *TT* coin can't yield *H*